# How to manipulate a node js server value in express ejs

Tags: javascript, express

I have an array of values sent from my node js server. I am trying to manipulate it using a raw javascript variable but the escaped varible wont accept outside values.

```
var df = event.target.id;
var t = ['<%=image %>']
```

alert(t[df])// prints a letter i.e m -> meaning it only read from the letters and not the array itself.

I was thinking since t is already an array, it would give me the value at position df but i am getting a letter value(i.e m)

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What's an example ID? Since `t` is an array, the ID would only access the IDth element in the array - anything other than 0 and it'll be undefined.

Comment: an example ID could be any number within the arrays total length. i.e 5,8 12

Comment: What is `image` ? How do you pass it to your template ?

Comment: image is an array sent from node js server.